# Form autosize to datagridview content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've a DataGridView binded to a List, displayed in a Form. As it's the main item of the form, I would love the form to fit the content of the DataGridView. Thanks to a question here, I've set up this code:

```
private void MessageForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // A few init stuff skipped
    m_isInit = true;
    init();
}

private void init(object list = null)
{
    if (!m_isInit)
    {
        return;
    }
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


    if (list == null)
    {
        list = MessageContainer.instance.messages.OrderBy(message => message.read).ThenByDescending(message => message.dateTime).ToList().toBindingList();
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);

    int height = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(row => row.Height);
    height += dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

    int width = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Sum(col => col.Width);
    width += dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;

    dataGridView1.ClientSize = new Size(width + 2, height + 2);
    Refresh();
}
```

It works well when the list has 1 item in it:

[image: working screenshot]

But it goes nuts as soon as the list is wider:

[image]

How can I fix this code to display the DataGridView correctly?

---

The Form has this:

```
AutoSize     : True
AutoSizeMode : GrowAndShrink
```

And no Min/Max size set.

---

### It seems that this question *needs* a bit more of informations.

My DataGridView is shaped in a FlowLayoutPanel which is in a From.

Here are the DataGridView's properties (just the ones about size/resize/autosize/style - can provide more on demand - Other values are set to *default*):

```
// 
// dataGridView1
// 
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.dataGridView1.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(878, 516);
this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellPainting);
```

Here are the flowLayoutPanel's properties:

```
// 
// flowLayoutPanel1
// 
this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.clearButton);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnCopyAll);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.cboxLevel);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.cboxExpertMode);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 525);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
this.flowLayoutPanel1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(878, 34);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1;
```

And here's the Form properties:

```
// 
// MessageForm
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(884, 562);
this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
this.Name = "MessageForm";
this.Text = "Errors, always errors...";
this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.MessageForm_Shown);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
this.flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```

I'm using all `Dock`, 'AutoSize' & so on properties with my best try to do want I want, but I can't make it work. Maybe I *didn't* catch the true meaning of theses properties.

Also, the `MessageForm` displays well when opened and the `MessageContainer.instance.messages.Count` is 1. If I opened the `MessageForm` with `MessageContainer.instance.messages.Count` being greater than 1, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think when you are working with windows forms, you should follow standard windows forms design approaches. Have you ever seen such design in windows? While probably this question can have answers, but I recommend you to don't follow that approach, What would happen if there are many rows in grid? what would happen if the user resize columns to be very wide? You can simply use dock or anchor and column size modes to have a responsive grid. :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei If I ask this, it's because I'm not happy with the way C# allow me to autosize my form. I've removed all the protection code to make the question easier to read. I appreciate the advice but I'll wait for a real answer :) (unless you now a way to make what I want to do just with properties)

Comment: Your question is completely well-formatted and there is no problem with the question at all. My comment is just an advice. The main problem with this design is exactly making the form auto size based on contents. I think the only thing you need is to allow user to change size of form and then align contents in a suitable alignment using dock, anchor, column size mode,etc properties.  At least for me as a user, changing the form size based on contents (Grid size) is annoying while I can change the form's size and the grid can be responsive to form size changes.

Comment: @varocarbas I understand that my question was not clear enough. Please consider edit and thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: I have explained my position quite clearly and delivered the kind of help which I think that is required here: 1. if you want to actually change the size of the form, modify your code accordingly (because now it only takes care of the size of DataGridView, via `dataGridView1.ClientSize = new Size(width + 2, height + 2);`); 2. When dealing with actions like resizing, you should take care of the user behaviour (i.e., by calling the method performing the given actions from the associated events). Behave as you wish, but respect others' behaviours (= I don't deliver what you are requesting).

Comment: @varocarbas ok thanks & sorry if I annoyed you, have a nice day :)

Comment: Why would you do this ? All my winforms project have the same functionality (requestes by the users): "Let us drag the columns where we want them, let us size the columns how we want them, and remember that settings for each grid for each user". Forms that autosize a datagrid are almost always received as annoying by users.

Comment: @GuidoG because I'm a dictator. Truth is that I didn't found a pretty way to display informations

Comment: Finding a pretty way to display information is not easy, that is very true. I like my forms to be practical, managment wants them sexy, users all want something else. That is why enable my users to make each form to their own liking